# OpenXML add custom style to Quick Style Gallery

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm creating a Word Document using OpenXML. During the creation of the document, I need to create some custom styles.

Now I've one problem left: I want to put my custom styles inside the Quick Style Gallery, but I wasn't able to do that. The way that I'm following is explained in the following code:

```
        var info = new LatentStyleExceptionInfo
        {
            Name = styleid,
            PrimaryStyle = true,
            UnhideWhenUsed = false,
            SemiHidden = false,
            UiPriority = 1
        };
        styleDefinitionsPart.Styles.OfType<LatentStyles>().First().Append(info);
```

Because I've found a link that tells that is the "PrimaryStyle" attribute responsible for put a Style inside the Quick Gallery.

Another thing: opening the styles.xml file, I've noticed that all the other styles has "1" or "0" for the OnOffValue, whereas the custom styles created with that piece of code has "true" or "false".

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The XML tag that influences appearance of the style in the quick gallery is `<w:qFormat/>`. The API property that corresponds is Style.QuickStyle. The Interop name is also QuickStyle (boolean).

Btw, I don't think adding a latent style is going to help you. You'll want to add a real, actual, fully-fledged style if you want it to appear in the UI and be operative.